# iOS User Interface for different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, device

I'm confused about how to handle user interfaces for different operating systems and devices at the same time.

If I want to support iOS 4.3+, and work for different devices of different screen sizes, how do I do it? Do I use struts/springs?

What about for 5.0+, do I use multiple storyboards and hardcode locations of view objects?

For 6.0+, do I use just one storyboard with autolayout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting 4.3+ then you should do everything with xibs, springs and struts. Trying to use storyboards for 5.0 and autolayout when on a 6.0 + device is just going to be a huge waste of your time.

But then I consider supporting 4.3+ rather than making iOS 5 your minimum a waste of time.

If you can possibly do it, you should make iOS 5 your minimum and use storyboards.